# Exact same code using same android studio why is the appBar not showing on one Mac

Tags: flutter

I have been making an app and I use git I bought a new Mac and everything was fine I tried to add web to my app on the Mac but it never worked so when I went to use the app again the default colour and the appBar colour have vanished I have tried every I have reset my MacBook back to factory settings and installed a fresh android studio and it is still not showing the appBar colour can anyone help please[the appbar is there but the colour isnt and on the other macs its using the material app colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzuz2.png)

I have removed android studio and factory reset the MacBook